# How to create ,Update the variable & how to get Updated variable in Mongo DB in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How to create , Update the variable & how to get Updated variable in `Mongo DB` in `Meteor`. And also how to send event to `Mongo DB`? I didn't have any idea about that. so Please help me how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get you started:

```
YourData = new Meteor.Collection("yourdata");

// Create
YourData.insert({text: "Some text in this record"});

// Get
var record = YourData.findOne();
var receivedTextFromDatabase = record.text;
console.log("Text: " + receivedTextFromDatabase);

// Update
YourData.update({_id: record._id}, {$set: {text: "Changed this text"}});
```

Then you'll have to declare the use of this collection (`YourData`) in your templates. Updating the collection will then automatically update your template and html. [The documentation](http://docs.meteor.com) is actually pretty good—check it out.

Comment: i have tried to as  you told same but i got the error i,e : Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403].So Please help me.@seldon

Comment: Are you doing the update in the exact same way or are you using your own selector instead of something similar to `{_id: record._id}`? You can only use `_id` as the selector when updating from the browser side.

Comment: Also please accept the answers in your questions if you find them helpful and correct. This helps people looking for a solution to the same problems zone in on the best working solution.

Answer (score 0):

The database API is all in the docs under [Collections](http://docs.meteor.com/#collections).  Things are actually a little more complicated than that as the client is in reality being provided with its own mini version of the MongoDB which is then being synced with the back-end database, as documented in [Data and Security](http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity), but given that the `autopublish` and `insecure` packages are already installed in new projects, you don't have to worry about this too much.  It should "just work".