# Meteor update worldwide access variables

Tags: meteor

I am trying to create a count variable in Meteor that, once updated, will be reflected by anyone viewing the app online. I also do not know the proper term for this variable so I apologize for the weak description. I have just started using Meteor today.

Basically, I need to be able to display a live count of the number of messages sent through the app. I have read that using a database would be discouraged because of how often the value will be changed. Is there a way to do this?

Here's what I've tried (in isClient, wwCounter is defined as wwCounter = 0; outside of isClient):

```
Template.wwCount.helpers
({
    wwCounter: function()
    {
        return Session.get('wwCounter');
    }
});
```

And in isServer (contained within the event function sendMessage after the message is sent. The message DOES send, no troubles there):

```
wwCounter++;
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to use the database when ever somebody subscribes to the database collection and it changes everybody gets updated. Session is just for the current user only.

Comment: "The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming."

Donald Knuth

Comment: Use the db, that's what it's for.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Turns out this question was asked before, but I didn't know how to search for it given the terms. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968821/how-to-create-update-the-variable-how-to-get-updated-variable-in-mongo-db-in